# Meteor methods and performance

Tags: meteor, minimongo, meteor-methods

We have some meteor methods in our application which are not really being used. There are also few methods available both at client and server side, but are "Actually" being used only on either of the 2 ends. 
Question: Can these things have an impact/major impact on the overall performance of the system?

Also, will there be a major difference in performance if we use Meteor methods or Rest APIs?

Answer (score 0):

Writing unused or barely-used methods will not really impact your performance, except if you've written thousands of them, in such case it will primarily impact the initial load and the restarts of your app when you modify it).

I never tried it but you can check if that works out for you: https://guide.meteor.com/code-style.html#eslint

Also, defining methods on either client or server side (and ending up calling them on both) is completely normal, it just depends on the variables/props you need.